# Posting JSON data to MVC controller using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying to pass JSON data into MVC4 controller, which hasn't worked so far.

Also, I've googled on this a thousand of times.

The key point to solve this issue out there was to stringify the JSON object, define a model and get the parameter as the defined model, or define contentType.

I did those but defining a model for passing JSON into controller.

If I have to define the model every time I try to pass JSON parameter to server, I'm not going to build my app on MVC4, I will give up!

Is there another way to get JSON data from Ajax call in a controller without creating a model for the JSON data?

Here's my example code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DATACRUD(string XmlParms)
{
    return Json(new{ data = XmlParms });
}
// Just example.
```

And Ajax call is.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DATACRUD.json",
        data: JSON.stringify({data:"test"}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false, //_async,
        success: function (result) {
        }
});
```

**Ajax successfully invokes the action in a controller, but the parameter is null.**

Please don't tell me defining model for the JSON parameter is the only one way to solve this issue.

It would be very frustrating if I have to do that.

---

UPDATE:

If I have to match the key name and the param name, I will give up as well.

JSON data usually looks like this in my app.

```
{
    "service": "COMMON",
    "method": "MENU_SUBLIST",
    "UID": "1000007",
    "ULID": "stackoverflow",
    "UNM": "queston", 
    "SITE": "1",
    "DEPT": "2",
    "LANG": "ko", 
    "MENUID": "0000",
    "STEPMENU": "",
    "ACTIONNAME": "" 
}
```

But the thing is that there're many kinds of JSON data including a variety of key names.

I cannot match the names all one by one. In this case, what should I do?

( **And just make sure**, wrapping the data like this below isn't a solution for me, **there's a compatibility issue.** )

```
{ XmlParms : {         
    "service":"COMMON",
    "method":"MENU_SUBLIST",
    "UID":"1000007",
    "ULID":"stackoverflow",
    "UNM":"queston",
    "SITE":"1",
    "DEPT":"2",
    "LANG":"ko",
    "MENUID":"0000",
    "STEPMENU":"",
    "ACTIONNAME":""
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "test" over here????

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify({XmlParms:"test"})`?

Comment: is correct action url in $.ajax ?

Comment: @mohammadrezaberneti Yes, it's correct. I set up in routeconfig for the url

Comment: **Is there another way to get JSON data from Ajax call in a controller without creating a model for the JSON data?** Well if you need multiple parameters without a model, you cant define only one parameter string. The model it's the best way to bind every parameter. If you need a string, maybe the "object" you are trying to send, somehow convert it to a string a then you can control how to split them. But I think a model it's the best solution

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Posting-JSON-Data-to-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Code-Examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing the small thing. Parameter name should be the same in ajax call.

```
    data: JSON.stringify({XmlParms:"test"}),
```

Comment: sir, I updated my question. could you give me another solution? :(

Comment: Thanks a lot. matching the param name is the first thing I needed.

Answer (score 0):

because your controller take argument named `XmlParms`, therefore in order to make it bind correctly, you must pass data with corresponding argument name

Assume that your json data will be assigned to a javascript variable name `jsonParams`. Then all you have to do is :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DATACRUD.json",
        data: {XmlParms:jsonParams},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "application/xml-urlencode",
        async: false, //_async,
        success: function (result) {
        }
});
```

You just need to pass it as pure string, and parse it back to json object in your controller

Comment: sir, I updated my question. could you give me another solution? :(

Comment: appreciated it but, setting a default key name is not a solution for me. I have to accept the json data no matter what the key name is

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the anonymous object syntax in your Action is incorrect; keys are given a value with `=`, not `:`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DATACRUD(string XmlParms)
{
    return Json(new { data = XmlParms });
}
```

Secondly, your action is expecting a parameter called `XmlParms`, yet you are only sending a string in AJAX. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DATACRUD.json",
    data: { XmlParms: "test" },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result.data); // = 'test'
    }
});
```

Note that you don't need to manually use `JSON.stringify` as jQuery will do this for you when you give an object to the `data` property.

Comment: sir, I updated my question. could you give me another solution? :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what your update means.

Answer (score 0):

I just remove
(contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",) property from
$.ajax({
.
.
.

});

The action become recive data from ajax!